# Inequality induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't know how to go on from here. This is what I have done so far minus the base case which is trivial.

Prove by induction the inequality:

$n^{n-3}\geq n!$ for $n\geq 9$

the hypothesis:

$j^{j-3}\geq j!$ for $j\geq 9$

the claim wit the induction step $(j+1)$:

$(j+1)^{(j+1)-3}\geq (j+1)!=j!(j+1)$ for $j\geq 9$

steps so far:

$(j+1)^{(j+1)-3}\Rightarrow$

$(j+1)^{(j-2)}\Rightarrow$

$\frac{(j+1)^{j}}{(j+1)^{2}}\Rightarrow$

Comment: the last par of the question (i.e. after "step so far") doesn't make sense...